# jQuery sortable events

Tags: jquery

Im using some jQuery sortables and I basically have two event handlers set up in the sortable init (receive and stop) The problem is, If the receive event fires then I don't want the stop event to fire. In other words, it's sending two ajax requests to my server when I only need one sent.

Is there some way to check if the receive event has already fired?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sample code would help some, but you can use things like `$(this).data({fired: false});` to store an attribute on the Sortable.  Then, in your Receive and Stop methods do something like `var props = $(this).data();  if (!props.fired) { // your execution code }` as a way of detecting it.  Inside of the execution block you'd include a line like `$(this).data({fired: true});` to record that it's been sent.

Comment: Slightly more compact: `if ($(this).data('fired')) ...` You also don't need to initialize it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Receive event will only fire if you're dragging an item from another list.
In your "stop" handler you can check which list the item has come from and do not send ajax request if it's the same list